# student positioning according to class

Tags: php

as an example, i have created a databases data has the following fields,

```
id,studentNo,class,mathsscore,mathposition,engscore,engposition,bioscore,bioposition,physcore,phyposition.
```

assuming the table looks like this:

```
id | studentNo | Class | mathscore | mathposition
-------------------------------------------------
1       10      Junior 1    56       ?
2       11      Junior 1    55       ?
3       12      Junior 1    66       ?
4       13      Junior 1    34       ?
5       14      Junior 1    87       ?
6       15      Junior 2    54       ?
7       16      Junior 2    56       ?
8       17      Junior 2    55       ?
9       18      Junior 3    87       ?
10      19      Junior 3    77       ?
```

so how can I echo out each student position according to their classes using php since the summation is done together in the same database that has different clases

Comment: Can you show us how you are attempting to get the results from the database?

Comment: what do you mean, "position". ranked by score, so students #5 and #9 are tied for first place? Plus, your table design is bad. what if you have to add another class type? e.g. "basketweavingscore"? your class types/scores should be in a child table.

Comment: You should check out mysql's GROUP_CONCAT. Depending on what you are trying to do. http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/10/22/the-power-of-mysqls-group_concat/

Answer (score 0):

Some tricky query using correlation. I'll show you for math only, and then you can think about others. The idea is to count number of students that has less or equal math score per each student. If I have score 30 and there are 15 students with score <= 30 then my position in the class is 30+1 = 31 (you can do it when showing)

```
SELECT a.studentNo, (SELECT count(*) FROM students b WHERE b.mathscore <= a.mathscore AND b.class = a.class) as position FROM students a;
```

p.s
May be slow...